# javascript disabled/enabled input text form

Tags: javascript, text, input

I have two input text forms.
When I select first input form the second one should become disabled, and vice-versa.
Here is html:

I have a piece of code that works fine in Chrome, but doesn't work in Firefox

```
    <div id='input-container'  style="width:155px; height: 30px;">
    <input onclick="somefunction()"  class="input"  style="width: 155px;" id='myText'  />
</div>
<br />
<div id='input-container1'  style="width:155px; height: 30px;">
    <input onclick="somefunction1()" class="input1" style="width: 155px;" id='myText1'  />
</div>
```

and here is Jquery:

```
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // disable all the input boxes
        $(".input").attr("disabled", true);
        $(".input1").attr("disabled", true);
        // add handler to re-enable input boxes on click
        $("div:has(.input)").click(function() {

        $("#myText").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#myText1").val(" ");
        $("#myText1").attr("disabled",true);
             });

        $("div:has(.input1)").click(function() {
        $("#myText1").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#myText").val(" ");
        $("#myText").attr("disabled",true);

    });
    });
</script>
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to solve this. Thanks to all suggestions above. Here is the solution:

**HTML**

```
 <span style="position:relative;">
  <input id="text1" type="text" disabled />
  <div id = "div1" style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0; cursor: pointer;" ></div>
</span>
<span style="position:relative;">
  <input id="text2" type="text" disabled />
  <div id = "div2" style="position:absolute; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0; cursor: pointer;" ></div>
</span>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#div1').click(function(){
    $('#text1').prop("disabled", false).focus();
    $('#text2').prop("disabled", true);
    $("#text2").val(" ");
});
$('#div2').click(function(){
    $('#text1').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#text2').prop("disabled", false).focus();
    $("#text1").val(" ");
});
</script>
```

Comment: just one word... awesome ... :)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id='input-container' class="input-container"  style="width:155px; height: 30px;">
<input onclick="somefunction()"  class="input"  style="width: 155px;" id='myText'  />
```

**JavaScript**

```
var containers = $('.input-container'),
    inputs = $('.input');

// disable
inputs.attr('disabled','disabled');

containers('click',function() {
   inputs.attr('disabled','disabled').val(' ');
   $(this).find('.input').removeAttr('disabled').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did:

```
@{
  object attributes = new { @class = "form-control" };
  object disabledAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled="disabled" };
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Vehicle_ModelYear, TabVehiclesModel.YearsDropdown, Model.ModelYearEnabled ? attributes : disabledAttributes)
```